# Ambiguity between packages in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

I was trying to update a migration in an MVC 5 project when suddenly I get all these errors:

> Type name 'NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstallerServices' is ambiguous, it could be 'NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstallerServices, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Authentication.ConnectedServices, Version=1.0.0.0, 
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or 'NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstallerServices, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Project, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   At E:\AllData\Dropbox\Pro Gaming\www\Pro_Gaming\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:1004 char:5
>   +     $packageInstallerServices = $componentModel.GetService([NuGet.Vis ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousTypeReference

Also:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   E:\AllData\Dropbox\Pro
>   Gaming\www\Pro_Gaming\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:1006 char:5
>   +     $vsPackage = $packageInstallerServices.GetInstalledPackages() | ? ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

And many other errors referring to null values product of this problem, which I have omitted in this post.

I first thought it was a problem with Visual Studio's NuGet so I reinstalled it. Then, I tried reinstalling Entity Framework.

Afterwards I decided to try installing EntityFramework and NuGet packages on a different MVC solution and it worked flawlessly.

I've also forced an uninstall and install of Entity Framework (both with -reinstall and updatePackage commands) to no avail. I have searched for any file name duplicates in the folder but I've yet to find one.

Also, "NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstallerServices" is nowhere to be found even in file contents of the same solution.

So the problem is with this specific solution!

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883705/get-error-while-running-enable-migrations and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b0c771a5-7a52-4eb4-907e-0fd9f2ff063a/type-name-nugetvisualstudioivspackageinstallerservices-is-ambiguous?forum=adodotnetentityframework

The issue was resolved for me by going one back step from Windows 10 build 11099 which seems to cause the issue.

Comment: The issue is still in 11102 :(

Comment: @StephenReindl: Nooooooooooooo :( Freaking hating that. Oh well... that's what happens when we want to be super fast with the insider builds.

Comment: See the answer from @stefan-z-camilleri as a working :) workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: The underlying  PowerShell issue is confirmed fixed in build 14291 of Windows 10 Redstone.

We have identified a change in the behavior with the latest preview builds of Windows and we are working with the Windows and Visual Studio teams to figure out the solution.

We will post any updates on this bug: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2872

Comment: The referenced bug on CodePlex is marked as "Resolved" yet the comment clearly states that the fix will only be available via a new Insider build of Windows, which hasn't happened yet. This really shouldn't be marked as resolved until it's actually resolved and working for all of us and why does an update to PowerShell (and/or EF) require a new OS build in order to fix the issue?

Comment: Because PowerShell ships with Windows. I think it is a valid interpretation like any other that the bug shouldn't be marked as resolved until the fix is available to the public. However that bug database belongs to the EF team and we don't have direct control over the distribution of the fix. In fact I switched the state to Resolved,  a state that we seldom use in that bug database, with the specific purpose of communicating the good news that we had a fix. I am planning to move the bug to the closed state only when we have verified the fix. This reflects common practice.

Answer (score 5):

Until Microsoft fix this issue, I have posted a workaround here for it -> http://edd.stefancamilleri.com/2016/02/14/update-database-fails-in-package-manager-console-on-windows-10-insider-preview-with-ambiguous-type-error/

You can use type aliases to get around it.

Update: In the meantime, MS have fixed the issue.  That said, this method will work if you encounter similar errors in the future.

Comment: Woot! Great! If I go back to the Preview program, I'll surely apply that!

Comment: Didn't work for me. Assuming you have to have Resharper installed for it to work properly? `Cannot convert argument "type", with value: "Nuget.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstallerServices, JetBrains.Platform.VisualStudio.SinceVs11, Version=104.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325", for "Add" to type "System.Type"`

Comment: The the type ambiguity in your specific case would have been between another two libraries.

The error generally gives you the fully qualified type name for both conflicting types, you simply need to use one of those.

My example is specific to my setup, so your could vary.

The alias approach should work though if you replace using the correct types.  Could you try?

Answer (score 2):

Without access to the project, that's hard to debug.  BUT - I can tell you that we migrated to VS2015 recently (and updated MVC) and got some of the same errors.

We ended up resolving by **taking a look a the .csproj and .sln files** in notepad++.  For us, there were references to assemblies in the file that weren't showing up in the VS2015 UI.

Deleting the old references manually, saving the csproj file(s) and then reopening the solution in VS2015 resolved the issue for us.

Comment: Thanks. I've been searching for the .csproj but haven't found any anomalies. 

Here is the link in case needed: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qvf0jf7oi3u197a/Pro_Gaming.csproj?dl=0