# Get error while running Enable-Migrations

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6, powershell-5.0

I got below error while running Enable-Migrations on my ASP.NET MVC5 project (Powershell v5 & Visual Studio 2015). I have tried to uninstall and re-install EntityFramework (v6.1.3) but no lucky.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

> Type name 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package' is ambiguous, it could be 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   At C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MSHGPU2S.W4I\Modules\NuGet\profile.ps1:126 char:5
>   +     $service = [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package]::GetGlobalServi ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousTypeReference
>
> Type name 'NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstallerServices' is ambiguous, it could be 'NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstallerServices, Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationInsights, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or 'NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstallerServices, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Application, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   At D:\xxx\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:1004 char:5
>   +     $packageInstallerServices = $componentModel.GetService([NuGet.Vis ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousTypeReference
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>   At D:\xxx\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:1006 char:5
>   +     $vsPackage = $packageInstallerServices.GetInstalledPackages() | ? ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
>   At D:\xxx\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:713 char:28
>   +     $toolsPath = Join-Path $installPath tools
>   +                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
>
> Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
>   At D:\xxx\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780 char:74
>   + ...  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-Path $ToolsPath EntityF ...
>   +                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>   At D:\xxx\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781 char:5
>   +     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance(
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
>   At D:\xxx\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:810 char:20
>   +         (Join-Path $runner.ToolsPath EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll),
>   +                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand

Comment: I'm having the same issue as you right now, could you tell me if you're using Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview Build 11099.rs1_release.160109-1156 or something similar? I think it could be related to the latest update, because yesterday everything was fine for me, so the system decided to update and then everything went to hell.

Comment: Surprisingly, it seems related to Build 11099: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b0c771a5-7a52-4eb4-907e-0fd9f2ff063a/type-name-nugetvisualstudioivspackageinstallerservices-is-ambiguous?forum=adodotnetentityframework  Based on that post, you can use the  migrate.exe command line to do your migration. But not sure if all the commands are available. Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx

Comment: Yes, I have updated to Build 11099 two days ago. So we have to revert to previous build and hope that this issue will be fixed in the future

Comment: Problem remains on 14251

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug if you have any of the Windows 10 Insider Preview builds from 11099 to 14257

Official bug report https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2872

Comment: We have identified a change in the behavior with recent preview builds of Windows and we are working with the Windows and Visual Studio teams to figure out the solution.

Comment: We will post any updates on the CodePlex issue posted by Robert MacLean above.