# Enttiy Framework - ambigous packages while using ps commands

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, nuget

I've following error while using PS commands related with Entity Framework (f.e. Update-Database):

> Type name 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package' is ambiguous, it
>   could be 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0, Version=14.0.0.0,  Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Yesterday everything was fine, no updates to Windows or VS were installed.

The problem causes "Update-Database" ran from nuget package console. It happens only with nuget commands related to Entity-Framework.

Comment: "PS" is PowerShell? How are those commands being executed? As a part of a script file, or embedded in your app? What is the command that's throwing that exception? From the details provided, it looks like it has nothing to do with Entity Framework.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883705/get-error-while-running-enable-migrations - caused by Windows it seems

Comment: Eh reverting to prev version of windows compiiation didn't helped.. Reinsrtalled whole system, without windows insider. Thanks!

Comment: @nopeflow are you using the Windows 10 Insider builds (14251 specifically)?  I'm having the exact same issue, and a few things stopped working for me in the latest Insider build release (I'm not positive this error has to do with it, but I think it might).  For example, Git.exe (Git for Windows) doesn't work with the latest build, and running the command `net /?` causes an error.  I believe some of the network and memory management stack has been revamped in this build, and it's causing some low-level issues in various places.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didnt' read the comments above before posting my comment :-X