# Visual Studio 2015, entity framework and enable-migrations error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

as usual I have a strange problem in Visual Studio 2015 with Entity Framework. I've created an entity project with one table and one context.

When in the Package Manager Console I tried to enable migrations with enable-migrations I receive the following error:

> Type name 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package' is ambiguous, it
>   could be 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package, 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or 
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. At C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT
>   VISUAL STUDIO
>   14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\34KI2DKF.CBD\Modules\NuGet\profile.ps1:126 char:5
>   +     $service = [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package]::GetGlobalServi ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousTypeReference   Type name 'NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstallerServices' is ambiguous, it
>   could be 'NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstallerServices, 
>   Xamarin.TestCloud.Integration, Version=3.11.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or 
>   'NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstallerServices,
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Migration.Shell, Version=3.11.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'. At
>   C:\Projects\Web\PSC.Shorturl.Web\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:1004
>   char:5
>   +     $packageInstallerServices = $componentModel.GetService([NuGet.Vis ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousTypeReference   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   C:\Projects\Web\PSC.Shorturl.Web\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:1006
>   char:5
>   +     $vsPackage = $packageInstallerServices.GetInstalledPackages() | ? ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull   Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null. At
>   C:\Projects\Web\PSC.Shorturl.Web\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:713
>   char:28
>   +     $toolsPath = Join-Path $installPath tools
>   +                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
>   Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is
>   null. At
>   C:\Projects\Web\PSC.Shorturl.Web\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780
>   char:74
>   + ...  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-Path $ToolsPath EntityF ...
>   +                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
>   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   C:\Projects\Web\PSC.Shorturl.Web\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781
>   char:5
>   +     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance(
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull   Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null. At
>   C:\Projects\Web\PSC.Shorturl.Web\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:810
>   char:20
>   +         (Join-Path $runner.ToolsPath EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll),
>   +                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand

Do you have an idea how I can resolve the problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883705/get-error-while-running-enable-migrations. Please see this